# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException while trying to call other Activity

Tags: android

I am trying to call, ProductsActivity.java whenever user do click on OK in AlertDialog in ProductInformationActivity.java, but always getting an Error **Caused by:java.lang.NullPointerException** at line number 76th, which is

```
   KEY_CATEGORY = bdl.getString("category");
```

**ProductInformationActivity.java:**

```
    alertdialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
int which) 
    {
      finish();
    }
});
```

**ProductsActivity.java:**

```
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
            // below is the line number 76
    KEY_CATEGORY = bdl.getString("category");
```

**Logcat:**

```
05-18 16:23:25.027: E/AndroidRuntime(922): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 16:23:25.027: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.menu.ProductsActivity.onCreate(ProductsActivity.java:76)
05-18 16:23:25.027: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-18 16:23:25.027: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-18 16:23:25.027: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-18 16:23:25.027: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: from where u passing ur data ?

Comment: check whether KEY_CATEGORY getting value from bundle or not

Comment: post code for ur Intent..when u are putiing value to that intent

Answer (score 0):

That error means there are no extras: `Intent.getExtras()` will return null if no extras were set  in the original Intent. You should wrap that in a conditional check like `if(getIntent().getExtras() != null){ Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras(); }`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this in one activity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ProductsActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("category", "yourStringHere");
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
```

And then do your code in ProductsActivity:

```
    Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
    KEY_CATEGORY = bdl.getString("category");
```